# Sharepoint Form based Authentication logout problem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I have used `forms based authentication` in my `SharePoint 2013` project. I added the following parameters to the `web.config` and made the form-based authentication settings from the `Central Administrator`. When user log on, there is no problem. Users are redirected to login page successfully. However, When user log out, user isn't redirected to login page. User is redirected to this page

> (/_layouts/15/signout.aspx).

Web.config parameters:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/Static/Pages/Giris.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

When user log out, user should be redirected to

> /_layouts/Static/Pages/Giris.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method to redirect user after logout, this worked without any problem to me.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWebApplication http://YourApp:Port/
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity Signout -RelativePath "/_layouts/Static/Pages/Giris.aspx" -WebApplication $web
```